# Is it possible to setup an ftp server that only allows file uploads?

Tags: ftp, uploading

Is it possible to setup an ftp server in such a way that only allows users (either registered accounts or anonymous accounts) to upload files and do nothing else (such as delete files, view other folders, chmod, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

I use VSFTPD on my servers which is easy to configure for real and virtual users, plus its very secure.

Open vsftpd.conf file:
`# vi /etc/vsftpd.conf`

Set download_enable to NO:
`download_enable=NO`

Save and close the file. Restart vsftpd ftp server:
`# /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart`